# Trouble installing gitlab-5.0 - rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

Trouble installing gitlab-5.0

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md#initialise-database-and-activate-advanced-features

```
root@ubuntu:/home/gitlab/gitlab# bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__807030537706508428__prepare__2182945095053453794__callbacks'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-2.6.7/lib/backports/tools.rb:314:in `require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-2.6.7/lib/backports/tools.rb:314:in `require_with_backports'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:setup => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 10):

If you are following the tutorial and followed the steps for the MySQL database setup then you have configured the database to use gitlab for the user name.

```
# Create a user for GitLab. (change $password to a real password)
mysql> CREATE USER 'gitlab'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password';
```

but if your database.yml file is attempting to log into the database using the root credentials.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "secure password"
  # host: localhost
  # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

That is why you would see that error.
Change your database.yml file to reflect the login created in the database setup portion of the tutorial.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 5
  username: gitlab
  password: "$password"
  # host: localhost
  # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 4):

That section [Initialise Database and Activate Advanced Features](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md#initialise-database-and-activate-advanced-features) is:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
```

That means you are supposed to execute that command as `git`, not as `root` (which hasn't been granted access to the database).

Make sure though that your `database.yml` config file looks like [this one](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/config/database.yml.mysql) (if you have mysql installed and want to use a mysql database).

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: gitlabhq_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: "secure password"
  # host: localhost
  # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

It does declare an access for an account `root`, but this is purely a declarative *mysql* account (nothing to do with the user `root`)

Comment: Interesting that they want you to sudo git when they specify (at least now) that git shouldn't get a password so it can't login, thus no sudo. Plus, git would have to be in the sudoers file. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/install/centos/README.md